# MySQL Stored Procedure in PHPMYADMIN -- nothing happens

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created this test procedure :

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE `str` (IN var1 INT)  
BEGIN
    WHILE var1 < 5 DO
        SELECT var1;
        SET var1 = var1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

when I run it via phpmyadmin, nothing happens. no error, no confirm message. If I `CALL str(1)`, I get a message saying the procedure doesn't exist. What's wrong here?

Comment: Please be aware that tags stand alone.  That is, combining the tags `stored` and `procedure` doesn't mean you're talking about stored procedures.

Comment: @Charles Who would talk about `stored-procedures` though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the iterated value of `var1` you need the `SELECT` outside of the `WHILE` loop. The following works fine in my MySQL install:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `str`;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE `str` (IN var1 INT)  
BEGIN
    WHILE var1 < 5 DO
        SET var1 = var1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT var1;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Executing `CALL str(1)` returns `5`